# upload multiple image with alamofire cause repeating first image

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire

it's the first time for me to upload array of images
i'm using `Alamofire` and upload is success
but i discover that it repeats the first image

[image]

```
    let selectedImages = NSMutableArray.init()
    for img in Photos {                    // photos = [UIImage]()
        selectedImages.add(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.1)!)
    }
    var s:String = mainTitleTextfield.text!
    if  s == "" || s == " " {
        let f = DateFormatter()
        f.dateFormat = "MMM d, yyyy"
        let date = Date()
        s = f.string(from: date)
    }
    s = s.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlPathAllowed)!
    let url = serverURL + "postPhotosToClasses/?AlbumName=" + s + "&IsGroup=\(false)"
    HUD.show(.label("uploading"))
    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

        for i in 0..<selectedImages.count {
            multipartFormData.append(selectedImages[i] as! Data, withName: "file",fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        }
        multipartFormData.append(selectedImages[1] as! Data, withName: "file",fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        _ = 3

    }, to: url,method:.post,
       headers:["UserID":"\(currentTeacher.ID)","Ids":arr], encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload
                .validate()
                .responseJSON { response in
                    switch response.result {
                    case .success(let value):
                        print("responseObject: \(value)")
                        HUD.flash(.success, delay: 1.0)
                    case .failure(let responseError):
                        print("responseError: \(responseError)")

                    }
            }
        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print("encodingError: \(encodingError)")

        }
    });

}
```

could be the problem in using for loop to append in `multipartFormData`

Comment: What for is the `multipartFormData.append...` _after_ the for loop?

Comment: i add this code to test if the problem in foor loop
but it case the same problem and upload selectedimage[0]

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in withName
when replace

```
for i in 0..<selectedImages.count {
  multipartFormData.append(selectedImages[i] as! Data, withName: "file",fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
  }
```

with this line 
by change `withName:"file"` to `withName:"file\(i)"`

```
for i in 0..<selectedImages.count {
  multipartFormData.append(selectedImages[i] as! Data, withName: "file\(i)",fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")  
  }
```